# ValueError: not a built-in stop list: indonesian

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I have an error on this called `ValueError: not a built-in stop list: indonesian.`

```
#Function to ngram
def get_top_n_gram(corpus,ngram_range,n=None):
    vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=ngram_range,stop_words = 'indonesian').fit(corpus)
    bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
    sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0) 
    words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
    words_freq =sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    return words_freq[:n]

#n2_bigram
n2_bigrams = get_top_n_gram(tw_list['text'],(2,2),20)

n2_bigrams
```

Already search in stack overflow but still don't really understand it. In stack overflow told that ‘English’ is currently the only supported string value. in reference that a person in stack overflow gave told that many language are available and Indonesian is one of them, but why the error says not a built-in ?? how to use stop words in Indonesian cause dataset that I use is in Indonesian.

Comment: If you're using scikit-learn then you should say so, and use the relevant tag. This question has nothing to do with jupyter except that you're probably running it in jupyter. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: [According to the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), `stop_words` can be `'english'`, or a list of words. There's no reason putting just "indonesian" would have worked. Use a _**list of indonesian stop words**_. The function's docs also have _"(see [Using stop words](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#stop-words))"_, which explain it further. Simply googling [indonesian stop words](https://www.google.com/search?q=indonesian+stop+words) gets you many resources.